# Drupal 7 Views Module - Can not add wrapper in view “content: title” field

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am setting up a blog.  I have developed several views to sort out the various types of articles “business, design, news, etc.”  On the article page and in the teaser however I would like to stye the “content: title” field. As seen in the example below.

In the research I have done it sounds as though you can accomplish this by creating a wrapper class in the “style settings” options in that titles configuration menu.

Here is where I am having difficulty.  When I select “Customize field and label wrapper HTML” for instance nothing happens.  I am not able to the field where I should be able to enter my custom wrapper class.  I have tried hitting “apply” then going back, I have applying the section and then saving the changes to the view, and I have tried applying saving and flushing the cache but with no result.

Is there a configuration some where that is preventing me from applying this option? Or am I doing something wrong.  It is frustrating to no end any advice would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add a wrapper in views "content:title" this is the most easiest way -

Just go to Title fields rewrite section. [image]

Comment: I gave it a shot but I am still not able to see the a wrapping container in firebug or any styling changes.  Are there other additional things I need to have configured?  Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: did tried with clear the cache? or will you check that your view is caching or not?

Comment: I did but without success.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap an element using **Style Settings** of that specific field. just click a field and there you can see the options. wrap label / field in your desired element.

Comment: Thats ideal what I would like to do.  But when I select one of those options and apply and save it does not take.  After doing so and going back to those options nothing is selected.  Is there something else I need to configure in order for it to stick?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @story you have to select a wrapping element(div,span) etc from the drop down list that just appeared after selecting an option inside style settings for that specific field.

Comment: Maybe that is the problem.  When I make the selection nothing appears.